# Troubleshooting MySQL jdbc database connector error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, centos, tomcat7

Need help troubleshooting MySQL database connect issue. First, when I run my Java web application on my development workstation I can successfully connect to my remote/hosted MySQL database.

When I deploy my Java web application to my hosted web server I get the following error `org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'`

I have the mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.bin.jar located in the WEB-INF/libraries folder within my application.  Like I said before, this seems to work fine when I run my web application on my local development machine, but fails when deployed to my web host.

Tomcat v7.x is running on my development workstation and my web host is using Tomcat v7.x as well. My development workstation is Windows based. I believe the web host is running CentOS7.x.

The other confusing part is my web application worked with my previous web host as written.

How can I get this problem resolved?

**EDIT 3/9/2016**

**Context.xml:**

```
<Resource
    name="jdbc/dbname_ccp"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="100"
    maxIdle="30"
    maxWait="10000"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://domain.com:3306/dbname_ccp"
    username="username_admin"
    password="dbname_password"
    validationQuery="select 1"
/>
```

**web.xml**

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>MySQL Datasource</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/dbname_ccp</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

I believe I have the correct user name, password, and database name since this same connection information works when I run my Java web application from my development workstation.  When Deployed to the hosted web server I get the following error:

```
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1452)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at utilities.DBConnection.getConnectionMySQL(DBConnection.java:33)
    at model.account.UserAccountDAO.Register(UserAccountDAO.java:286)
    at model.account.ProcessUserAccount.register(ProcessUserAccount.java:237)
    at controller.AccountServlet.performTask(AccountServlet.java:50)
    at controller.AccountServlet.doPost(AccountServlet.java:76)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:278)
    at  org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
    ... 24 more
```

I've tried including the mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar file in my project application WEB-INF/lib folder as well as in the tomcat /lib folder.  It doesn't seem to matter where I place the jar, the server deployment always fails with the error listed above.

How can I get this problem resolved?  Is there any other MySQL connection options?

Comment: Does anyone else have any further troubleshooting ideas?  I'm still unable to run my Java web application from web host's server. Thanks, Dave

Answer (score 0):

I have meet this problem before,my solution is to add the mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.bin.jar to *tomcat/common/lib* instead of  in *web app libraries*  and solved it.

Comment: I've tried locating the mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.bin.jar in numerous folders on the Tomcat server, including the lib folder, to no avail. They all resulted in the same error.

Comment: 1.You can check if database port 1433 is opened.

Comment: 2.check  /lib folder about  msbase.jar、mssqlserver.jar、msutil.jar

Comment: Not really in control of the database.  Plus it works when I run it from my local workstation. What does msbase.jar, mssqlserver.jar, msutil.jar have to do with this issue. These appear to be related to Microsoft SQL Server not MySQL.